# XML selecting nodes values

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML:

```
<NET_SETTINGS>
   <MAC_ADDRESS VALUE="bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa"/>
   <IP_ADDRESS VALUE="10.1.1.1"/>
</NET_SETTINGS>
```

and trying to get the string `VALUE` of either mac/ip element like so:

```
XmlNode macnode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/NET_SETTINGS/IP_ADDRESS");
string mac = macnode.Value;
```

I can see that it selects the correct node while stepping through the code, but the `macnode.Value` is always null and the `OuterXml` is this:

```
"<MAC_ADDRESS VALUE=\"bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa\" />"
```

Why does `Value` not get populated correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Value` is [`null` for `Element` nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx).

You want `macnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("VALUE").Value`

Comment: sd_dracula can you do @Esailija a favor and click the checkmark? The checkmark shows that it was the correct answer and marks your post answered.

Answer (score 2):

`VALUE` is an attribute.

```
string value = macnode.Attributes["VALUE"].Value
```

Answer (score 2):

By default the **Value** property will return the inner of the XML element which does not exist in this case . . .

```
<MAC_ADDRESS VALUE="bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa"/>

is equivalent to . . .

<MAC_ADDRESS VALUE="bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa"></MAC_ADDRESS>
```

The OuterXML will return the entire element markup.  So thats why you get the entire element back.

Since you stored it as an attribute you have to refer to it as an attribute

```
XmlNode macnode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/NET_SETTINGS/IP_ADDRESS");
string mac = macnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("VALUE").Value;
```

Should get you the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

`macnode.Value` is the text value, not the value of the `VALUE` attribute. You need the `Attributes` property of `macnode`, then get the attribute value for the `VALUE` attribute from that. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattributecollection.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this all with one XPath selection:

```
XmlNode macnode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/NET_SETTINGS/IP_ADDRESS/@VALUE");
string mac = macnode.Value;
```